# form submit and page redirect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need some advise handling a form submit and page redirect. I have two pages, where the first is a landing page with a simple form, when user select a criteria and submits it, he is redirected to page2 that displays tabular data and some query related info.

When Submiting Page1 Form, data is passed in the url :

```
for ( var key in dataArray )
{ 
    if ( dataArray[key] )
    {
        if (queryStr != "") 
        {
           queryStr += "&" ;
        }

        queryStr += key + "=" + dataArray[key];
    }
}

var url = "page2.html?" + queryStr;
window.location.href = url;
```

On the other hand, I am handling this POST using $_GET['xxx']), then build a query accordingly.The issue is not handling POST & GET requests but handling errors..

I dont like is that if the user types something in the url

`www.site.com/page2.html?Q1=red`  -> `www.site.com/page2.html?Q1=red545454`

it will logically not pass the server side validation and therefore just display an empty page template without data, which kind o bothers me..

Also if the user tries to load page2.html without any posted data(querystring).

I would like upon page2.html load event, check if there are any posted values, if not redirect back.. Is this the correct way of handling it? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You doesn't submit form through POST method because "on submitting" you use`window.location.href` (redirect) with param `Q1` in query string.

If you want see  only url like `www.site.com/page2.html` do next: set action to your form as `action="www.site.com/page2.html"`,instead adding variable  to `QUERY_STRING` dynamically insert  `Q1` in any `hidden` element like:

```
document.getElementById('Q1_ID').value = dataArray[key];
```

After call like `document.forms[0].submit();`. Now variable `Q1` in `$_POST['Q1']` and url look as `www.site.com/page2.html`.

Answer (score 0):

An elegant way to handle this would be to submit your form using Ajax and respond with validation errors or success message. In case of errors, show them on the current page otherwise redirect user to whatever page you want.